# Configure AWS CloudFront to add a default metadata param to the uploaded files

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I need to have the `Content-Disposition = “attachment”` set to all files uploaded to the s3 bucket.

How do I configure CloudFront to create this param and added it to metadata ?

I configured the CloudFront distribution with a whitelist header containing **Content-Disposition**
The post request is correct since the file is being uploaded successfully but not the metadata param.

Is there any possible fix for this issue?